# This program is unable to dispay the jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

i have written a code using jquery which displays an output just below the input text box at the click of a button and i have 2 things to display ...one is a square root other is a a simple database query but i can display only 1 at a time

[image]

test4.jsp

```
 <script src="//malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function()
          {
            $('#number').fadeOut(2500); //prop('disabled', false);
          });
        $("#enable").click(function()
          {
            $('#number').prop('disabled', false);
          });
          $("#show").click(function()
          {
            $('#number').show(2500,function()
          {
            alert("u can enter the values now");
          });
          });
        });     // enable ..show ..hide 

       $(document).ready(function() 
        {
        $('#form').submit(function() {

    var number = $('#number').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:       "post",
        url:        "test5.jsp",
        data:       "number=" + number,
        success:    
                   function(msg) 
                    {
                          //$('#result').hide();
                          //$("#result").html("<h3>" + msg + "</h3>").fadeIn("slow");
                          $("#result2").html("<h3>" + msg + "</h3>").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
return false;
});
});
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
Enter number:
    <input id="number" type="text" name="numb" disabled/>
    <input id="enable" type="button" value="Enable">
    <input id="show" type="button" value="show">
     <input id="hide" type="button" value="hide">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate Square Root" name="submit"/>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
```

test5.jsp code

```java
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.* ,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.*,          abc.database"%>

<%
int numb = 0;
if(request.getParameter("number").matches("9"))
   //if (request.getParameter("number").value 
{
numb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));
out.println("Square root of " + numb + " is " + Math.sqrt(numb));
} 
else {
out.println("Enter a number!");
}  
%>

<%
            Connection conn = null ;  
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null ;
 %>
<%               
            database obj =new database();
            conn = obj.connect(); 
     ps = conn.prepareStatement("select field2 from test4 where field1 = "+numb+"");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
            {
            String x = rs.getString(1);
            out.println("the value is "+x);
         }  
        conn.close();     rs.close();         
%>
```

NOTE --> i have tested the ..the DB connection works fine ..actually only one of them works either it gives the DB o/p or the square root

Comment: When posting questions you should make sure that your code is readable. Your _js_ is formatted that bad with wrong indenting that it is hard to read and understand.

Comment: Have you tested whether you are able to retrieve values from the db (try alerting or logging the value on console) ?

Comment: @Playmaker yes i have tested the ..the DB connection works fine ..actually only one of them works either it gives the DB o/p or the  square root

Comment: DB connection may work fine at the servlet/jsp level. But are you able to get the required output via AJAX?

Comment: @Playmaker i get the desired o/p via jquery

Comment: Does your DB have an entry corresponding to '2'?

Comment: `int numb = 0` ...this was the mistake ...silly one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: As per your currently provided code, the sqr root will only be printed if number = '9'**

```
if(request.getParameter("number").matches("9"))
```

If you don't mind having a little html formatting as part of the servlet reply, try this:

```
 <script src="//malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function()
          {
            $('#number').fadeOut(2500); //prop('disabled', false);
          });
        $("#enable").click(function()
          {
            $('#number').prop('disabled', false);
          });
          $("#show").click(function()
          {
            $('#number').show(2500,function()
          {
            alert("u can enter the values now");
          });
          });
        });     // enable ..show ..hide 

       $(document).ready(function() 
        {
        $('#form').submit(function() {

    var number = $('#number').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:       "post",
        url:        "test5.jsp",
        data:       "number=" + number,
        success:    
                   function(msg) 
                    {
                          //$('#result').hide();
                          //$("#result").html("<h3>" + msg + "</h3>").fadeIn("slow");
                          $("#result2").html("<h3>"+msg+"</h3>").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
return false;
});
});
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
Enter number:
    <input id="number" type="text" name="numb" disabled/>
    <input id="enable" type="button" value="Enable">
    <input id="show" type="button" value="show">
     <input id="hide" type="button" value="hide">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate Square Root" name="submit"/>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
```

**test5.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.* ,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.*,          abc.database"%>

<%
 String toPrint = "";
int numb = 0;
numb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));
if(request.getParameter("number").matches("9"))
   //if (request.getParameter("number").value 
{
numb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number")); 
toPrint += "Square root of " + numb + " is " + Math.sqrt(numb);
} 
else {
toPrint += "Enter a number!";
}  
%>

<%
            Connection conn = null ;  
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null ;
 %>
<%               
            database obj =new database();
            conn = obj.connect(); 
     ps = conn.prepareStatement("select field2 from test4 where field1 = "+numb+"");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
            {
            String x = rs.getString(1);
            toPrint += "<br/>the value is "+x;
         }  
        conn.close();     rs.close();
        out.print(toPrint);         
%>
```

Comment: this is giving same result

Comment: Just to get it clear - The issue is that you are getting either db output OR the squareroot in #results2 but you want both to appear.. right?

Comment: Note: as per your code, the sqr root will only be printed if number = 9

Comment: yes but if i dont enter 9 it will display `Enter a number`

Comment: Can you please paste a sample output. (Screenshot preferred)

Comment: i have added a Screen shot in the question

Comment: You added in my answer! Swtiched it to question

Comment: thanks man i got my mistake ... numb was initialized to 0 thats why the DB part wasnt running

Comment: Good! Pleasure helping :)